# "The OutputPath property is not set for project" when OutputPath is set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4, if I create a new build configuration for all projects in a solution, I get the following when building the web .csproj alone:

```
msbuild Company.Directory.Web.csproj /p:Configuration=Dev
```

> [Error]
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(483,
>   9): The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'Company.Directory.Web.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you
>   have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for
>   this project.  Configuration='Dev'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be
>   seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without
>   a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or
>   Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

However, the `OutputPath` property is set!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Dev|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>false</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>false</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>
    <DeployIisAppPath>Port 80/directory/dev</DeployIisAppPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{285FBF79-7933-4AF9-AAAF-25EE7734AAAA}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Company.Directory.Web</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Company.Directory.Web</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
    <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- ... -->
```

**Is this a bug? How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It turns out that the first `PropertyGroup` is important. Visual Studio inserted the new configuration (Dev) `PropertyGroup` before it for some reason. I'm guessing its a bug. I fixed it by moving the new configuration after the others.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{285FBF79-7933-4AF9-AAAF-25EE7734AAAA}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Company.Directory.Web</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Company.Directory.Web</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
    <RestorePacCompanyes>true</RestorePacCompanyes>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Dev|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>false</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>false</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>
    <DeployIisAppPath>Port 80/directory/dev</DeployIisAppPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: +1 3 hours of trying duff solutions and bang this one hit the spot, cheers! Paul

Comment: huh!!... this saved so much of frustration and time .. thanks

Comment: Perfect - fixed my issue immediately!

Comment: Deffo try it with \p:Platform="AnyCPU" instead of \p:Platform="Any CPU". That worked form me! Was looking at this for ages!

Comment: \p:Platform="AnyCPU" is awesome.

Answer (score 6):

I had similar error when trying to build from the command line with msbuild.exe. My problem was I was specifying 'Any CPU' when I should have put 'AnyCPU'.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with `Azure` project. After I added new configuration `Release-CLOUD-STAGE` into solution, I started to receive the same error:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project

After I opened the `ccproj` file in editor and searched for the new configuration, I saw this near the end of it:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release-CLOUD' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release-CLOUD\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release-CLOUD-STAGE' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release-CLOUD-STAGE\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

everything looked fine to me - existing configuration `Release-CLOUD` worked well, but new one did not. Turns out that there are **TWO `PropertyGroup` elements** in that project file - one - COMPLETE - in the very beginning of the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release-CLOUD|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release-CLOUD\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and then for some reason there is another one, SHORT version I showed above, inserted close to the end of the file. After I created proper COMPLETE version of the `PropertyGroup` element for new `Release-CLOUD-STAGE` configuration (and removed both SHORT versions) - everything complied.

I'm not sure if that's Azure-specific but I did waste some time on this so I would like to share my findings as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had two PropertyGroup elements without conditions, and I think the latter was preventing the former from taking effect.  I consolidated all of the child items into the first PropertyGroup element and got rid of the second, and things started working after that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for an Azure WebRole-project and added the `<PropertyGroup>` elements manually into the .csproj file. However, I accidentally put them below a couple of `<Import>` statements. The build will fail with the error in the question.

**Right order**

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Dev|AnyCPU'">
   <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
   <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
   <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
   <DebugType>full</DebugType>
   <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
   <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
   <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

**Wrong order**

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Dev|AnyCPU'">
   <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
   <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
   <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
   <DebugType>full</DebugType>
   <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
   <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
```