# The OutputPath property is not set for project

Tags: msbuild, jenkins

Building my Jenkins/MSBuild solution gives me this error

```
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(483,9): error : 
The OutputPath property is not set for project '<projectname>.csproj'.  Please check to
make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform 
for this project.  Configuration='Latest'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this 
message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have
specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. 
[C:\<path>\<projectname>.csproj]
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I have this in my .csproj file

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Latest|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Latest\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: have you tried passing in properties for OutputPath from the command line? Somewhere in a proj that propertygroup is wrong or missing i think.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Open up your csproj in a text editor and see if you have a property group section, should look something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Latest|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Latest\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Do you have a 'Latest' build configuration? If not add the above section to the csproj.

Comment: how is this an answer? this is a question deviating from the question asked.

Comment: maybe you just dont understand that that is the answer.

Comment: I have no clue, but 16+ people and the person who asked thinks it is the answer! So let us leave it at this :)

Comment: I had the same problem a couple of times; but I did have the configuration PropertyGroup in place, the problem? it was almost at the bottom of the file... anyhow I moved it to the top just after the default 'Debug|AnyCPU' config and that did the trick.

Comment: I have more than one PropertyGroup in the csproj file. one with Condition ... Debug|AnyCPU" and one with "Condition .. Release|AnyCPU". If I change the Debug to Latest, then I get a bunch more errors. Not surprsing in retrospect.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer please?

Comment: @AlLelopath You should just add a new property group section, not edit existing ones.

Comment: For me the csproj file was OK. The issue was not passing in the ' '/p:Platform=AnyCPU' ' Please see @saurabh answer [pass platform parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45305693/255117)

Comment: of course you can pass all the properties every time you build it but thats why you add the config so you don't have to.

Comment: in my case, the csproj contained the <PropertyGroup> for 'Debug|x64' but it only contained a <PlatformTarget> element and nothing else. i copy/pasted the elements from a similar project and was good to go.

Comment: Mine was actually missing the <OutputPath> tag! How that is possible and Visual studio can show a value in the interface is a wonder to me, but added it manually and now it is working! Yay!

Comment: @a4bike I'm adding configuration manually and that was the case for me.

Answer (score 143):

I have figured out how it works (without changing sln/csproj properties in VS2013/2015).

1. if you want to build .sln file:

   1. `/p:ConfigurationPlatforms=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"`
2. if you want to build .csproj file:

   1. `/p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=AnyCPU`

      1. notice the `"Any CPU"` vs `AnyCPU`
3. check the code analysis, fxcop, test coverage(NCover) targets, as well as the MSBUILD should be located properly. In my case its:

   1. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`
      but it can be different as you can see microsoft has given 6 cmd options to build code base::AMD (with cross plt, x86 & x64 options) and Windows(cross, x86, x64) and that also when code development happened with default JIT (it can be PreJIT ngen.exe, econoJIT)

I think more than this troubleshooting can be handle using power shell + msbuild. May be helpful for someone ...

Comment: I wish this response would get more votes. I had the configuration properly set, the issue was that I was not passing the '/p:Platform=AnyCPU' argument when executing the build (on a build machine). Passing the argument solved the issue. Thanks @Saurabh

Comment: Everything was setup correctly in my proj file. This answer was the missing piece to the puzzle. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too. The .csproj file was all set. Just needed to pass in that Platform parameter. Cheers

Comment: That space! In TFS 2017, I had to go to the variables tab of my build and change "Any CPU" to "AnyCPU"

Comment: Thanks! Fixed my CICD build in Azure DevOps

Comment: The space vs no-space issue was my problem. Why on earth would they make that distinction? Arg!

Comment: Thank you. You came as a saviour to me. I just can't thank you enough.

Comment: Same here, "Any CPU" vs "AnyCPU" typo!!

Comment: In my pipeline targeting console app PROJECT, it worked after using 'AnyCPU' and adding '/p:OutputPath=bin\Release\' in VSBuild task. Used COpyFiles task with '**\bin\Release\*' input to get output in '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' to be published.

Comment: thanks for this answer. and specifically for "Any CPU" vs AnyCPU

Answer (score 31):

As mentioned by perlyking, rather than editing the csproj XML The following worked for me. Here are the steps I used.

1. Open the Project Properties.
2. Select the Build Tab.
3. Under the Output section, Check that an output path is set. (if not set one, save the project and it should work).
4. If it is set, click on the "Browse..." button of the output path.
5. When the folder selection dialog opens, Navigate up one level in the
   file browser and then re-select the output folder and click
   the "Select Folder" button.
6. Save the project properties and it should work.

Comment: thanks! this worked for me. I *think* this needed to be refreshed because I renamed the build configuration

Comment: I also had this, after renaming my build configurations.  I didn't need to manually alter the .csproj file, but I did need to quit VS2015, then go back into VS2015.   And then it worked  (sigh..!)

Comment: Is incredible but this work,I selected the up level folder, then select the debug folder again ( the same that had selected ) and works. Thanks.

Comment: this only worked for me if I made sure the output path was "bin\" with nothing after it

Answer (score 18):

To add to what @James said, I found that if I looked at the project Compile properties in VS2013, the Build Output Path *was* specified. But when I examined the `.csproj` file directly, the `OutputPath` element was missing for the relevant build configuration. So in VS I simply made and reversed a minor edit to the output path, saved it, and that kicked the value into the project file, and I was then able to build.

Comment: 5 years later... VS2019 and this is still an issue - and this fix still works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was running into this issue while updating an older project with additional project configurations for per-environment config transforms.

It turns out that when the project configurations were added to the csproj file, they were inserted after an **Import** element which caused the issue.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'ProjectName.Dev|AnyCPU'">
...
```

Moving the **Import** element after all the **PropertyGroup** definitions fixed the problem for me.

Relevant similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31072208/2452820

Comment: This was the solution for me in VS2017.  Does anyone know whether this has been fixed in >= VS2019?

Comment: Thanks, finally solved my issue!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I was using MSBuild to build multiple .sln files, and had added a new step to build a .csproj file as well, when I encountered this error.

@Saurabh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45305693/4450733) highlighted the root of the problem. However, when fixing it, adding `/p:Platform=AnyCPU` to the MSBuild Arguments section didn't fix it. I actually needed to update the Platform value on the build step.

All other build steps were using the `$(BuildPlatform)` variable value (which happened to be "any cpu", with a space in it).

(Had I been building multiple .csproj files, I probably would have created a second variable for the AnyCPU platform.)

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio Build step]

Answer (score 2):

I got this error only when I was publishing my web project.  I had mistakenly selected the wrong build configuration when setting up the publish profile.

Answer (score 2):

For me the answer was to fix all the projects in **Build > Configuration Manager**.

If you have some projects where the name or platform does not match the solution configuration, you should change it so they all match.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that it can look correct in here but if you have updated a project outside of the sln you might need to make a dummy change and get it to update

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error happened because the output folder included a dot to make it relative to the current directory. The problem was solved by removing the dot.

The offending `Build output path` was:

`.\bin\Output`

The problem was solved by changing it to

`bin\Output`

The build output path can be found in the `Build` tab of the project properties, and there is a different path for each combination of `Configuration` and `Platform`.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. I have updated my windows platform by using command line. Currently i got updated to windows@5.0.0 version. Then you need to search for file name "SQLite3.UWP.vcxproj". Try to change "v141" to "v140". Currently I am using Visual Studio 2015 professional. If it's Visual Studio 2017, then there is no need to change version in SQLite3.UWP.vcxproj file.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the issue for some service fabric stuff in MSBuild.

First step was right clicking each affected project and pulling up their Properties, selecting the Build tab, then setting the platform target to x64.

Second step was to go into the configuration manager and set each project to also use x64 for Debug and Release.

This was for a VS2017 project.

Answer (score 1):

This error is misleading and can be caused by a different issue.  Check the entire message:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project 'myproject'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='myconfig'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  This error may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent Configuration or Platform.

My build configuration was missing this node in the csproj:

```
<PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
```

Despite saying AnyCPU was the selected Platform in the dropdown, the actual xml was not there.  Adding it fixed the mismatch between the project and the other project it was referencing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a few projects. After adding a new configuration to the projects, the PropertyGroup was added at the very end of the Project file.

Moving the PropertyGroup to right after all the other configurations PropertyGroup fixed the issue.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had this witha  slightly unusual SLN/CSPROJ file arrangement:

I had project files:

- A.csproj, with configurations "Dev" and "Production"
- B.csproj, with configurations "Dev" and "Production"
- C.csproj, a "common" library used by both A and B with configurations "Dev" and "Production"

And I had SLN files:

- AC.sln, with configuration "Production" - this is used by jenkins to build project A and the common library
- BC.sln, with configuration "Production" - this is used by jenkins to build project B and the common library
- ABC.sln, with configuration "Dev" - this is used by developers in VS to write new code without having to keep opening different solutions (this answer is a simplified view of a 55-project solution)

I'd made an edit to the common library and introduced a dependency on project A. AC.sln would still build in jenkins but BC.sln gave an error saying:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project 'A.csproj'.  Please check to
>   make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform 
>   for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='AnyCPU'.

It was initially puzzling because we don't even have a Debug config anywhere in any project; find in files for `Debug|` turned up 0 hits

ABC.sln that the human developers use in VS would also build fine. Building BC.sln gave an error that A.dll wasn't found

When the circular irresolvable problem of C depending on A was removed, everything started working again

Answer (score 0):

The *OutputPath property is not set for project* error message will appear if a `Platform` environment variable exists (as seems to happen on HP laptops) and the target of MSBuild contains a reference to another Visual Studio project.

After renaming the Platform environment variable my build now works.

It seems the parameter `/p:Platform="Any CPU"` gets applied to the target solution but doesn't 'carryover' to referenced projects. In my instance, the error message indicated referenced projects were using the environment variable `Platform=MCD`.

Answer (score 0):

I had two project configs, `Debug` and `Release`.  When the `Release` build was used, it was throwing this error.  The issue I found was that in the `csproj` file, the `Debug` config was near the top and the `Release` config was all the way at the bottom.

Manually moving the `Release` build just below the `Debug` build fixed it.

I'm assuming I did something incorrectly when setting up my build configurations because this doesn't feel like something I should have had to manually adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the properties of the project:
Make sure "Configuration Properties->General->Output Directory" is not blank. Note, it's not called OutputPath here. You can probably copy the value from Intermediate Directory.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problems when build `TheXTech` (https://github.com/Wohlstand/TheXTech/wiki/Building-on-Windows#building-in-visual-studio-201520172019-and-cmake) recently. And finally I found it is a `cmake -A` issue. The correct arch for 64 bit on windows is `x64`, not `Win64`.

For some more reference, see  https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html#platform-selection, https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2019-April/069379.html.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Solution properties and change the configuration to Any CPU or X64 or X86, and if build is checked uncheck that for what you are getting error for. By default, project build that for build configuration in solution and throw error as mentioned when building the project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your project file in editor
2. You can add

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Just below other build configuration settings - this will ensure paths are set for ALL possible CPU configurations with relevant build type. Msbuild selects and applies options reading file from top to bottom, so this will enforce to use paths regardless of other settings.