# Building MassTransit

Tags: c#, ruby, rake, masstransit

I am wanting to try out MassTransit but I am falling at the first hurdle.

Firstly the [downloads link](https://github.com/masstransit/masstransit/downloads) does appear to go to the right place. So I decided I'd just get the source and build it. However there is a dependency on Ruby and a couple gems (kinda irritating to a c# developer who has never used Ruby before), I installed Ruby and the gems and tried to run the build.bat, and I now get....

```
Building for .NET 3.5
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- zip/zip
C:/dev/MassTransit/rakefile.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

so I re ran it with the --trace and I get...

```
Building for .NET 3.5
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- zip/zip
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/albacore-0.3.5/lib/albacore/unzip.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/albacore-0.3.5/lib/albacore.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/albacore-0.3.5/lib/albacore.rb:9:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/albacore-0.3.5/lib/albacore.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
C:/dev/MassTransit/rakefile.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Unfortunately I am none the wiser...Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a folder called `zip` and inside that folder is there a file called `zip.rb`? Inside rakefile.rb you might need to change `require` to `require_relative`. The problem might also be in this file: `C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/albacore-0.3.5/lib/albacore/unzip.rb`

Comment: @Rots Thanks for the comment...did I mention that I have 0 ruby experience? There is no zip folder. When you say I might need to require_relative do you mean change all of the require to require_relative ? and when you say problem might be in the <..longpath..>/unzip.rb file ummm ok...what problem ?

Comment: Sorry Tim, I should have been more clear for you. The line `cannot load such file -- zip/zip` indicates that it is looking for a file named `zip.rb` under a `zip` folder somewhere. It could be in `C:/dev/MassTransit/` or any of the gem folders, eg for the albacore gem that is `C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/albacore-0.3.5/lib/albacore`. Either the rakefile.rb or any one of the gems (likely albacore) is looking for this zip requirement. Maybe check the albacore unzip.rb as a first check, looking for the require. It would be at the top of the file, looking like this `require zip/zip`

Comment: ok, so while I was trying things, I suddenly thought that maybe zip was another gem that I needed to install, and that seemed to work...then I had the next error, this time it was semver that i needed to install (so far this experience has been less than satisfactory) now build, seems to have all it needs...but onto the next problem....Now I am getting "The outputpath property is not set for project 'MassTransit.csproj'

Comment: Sounds like a nasty install procedure! Is it open source? You could patch it :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15134384/the-outputpath-property-is-not-set-for-project

Comment: Yeah, I am certainly finding it difficult to get this up and running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use NuGet.  The binaries are already there and you'll be sure to get the right stuff. You'll also need a transport package, such as MassTransit.RabbitMQ or MassTransit.MSMQ.

There are instructions on building in the README. If you really want to build from source start there. If they don't work for some reason a more to the mailing list and we can update the README.

Lastly, TeamCity builds MassTransit for you if you want a non-NuGet build, http://TeamCity.codebetter.com. Sign in with guest, find the MassTransit project and you can download the artifacts.

Comment: will NuGet give me all that I need? What about the RuntimeServices stuff. And what about deployment ?

Comment: You only need RuntimeServices if you are using MSMQ. You'll need to download the build from TeamCity then. Develop branch is at http://teamcity.codebetter.com/repository/download/bt8/80952:id/MassTransit-2.8.0.zip. In the services folder you'll find the RuntimeServices.

Comment: I would really suggest using RabbitMQ over MSMQ unless you have a very solid reason to use MSMQ. RabbitMQ is a much more robust platform, plus you don't need additional infrastructure.

Comment: I will need DTC as well, I thought that means I need to go the MSMQ route. Thanks for your help by the way. Its a bit frustrating that the MassTransit website is so lacking (and broken download link) in accurate information on how to get started. Have to say, its putting me off the product quite a bit, will my experience with the rest of the product be as bad?

Comment: It shouldn't be, building isn't for most people and you really shouldn't have to try. I've tried updating our wordpress site but the theme isn't saving the changes. I'll have to kick that over to the guy who runs it. If you do have issues the mailing list will often get you quicker answers than here.